# processing: How can make a function that's finding me the results of an quadratic formula with an array?

Tags: java, arrays, processing

I have an assignment to do and have no clue how to do it.

given is a quadratic equation:

```
y = a*x*x + b*x + c
```

thats my code so far:

```
void setup(){
    println(quadratic(4, 6, 1));
}

float quadratic(float a, float b, float c){
    return (-b + sqrt( b*b - 4*a*c)) / (2*a);
}
```

I have to write an function that's giving me the coefficients as parameters and the results as an array.

I just don't know how to make an array.

thank you so much in advance!

Comment: It's really hard to help with general "how do I do this" type questions. You're going to have to [break your problem down into smaller steps](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and approach those steps one at a time. Then if you get stuck, post a [mcve] along with a more specific question. Good luck.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Looks like you need to encode [the quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) into Java.

Comment: I updated my post. It would be very nice if u would help me with the array

Comment: Thanks for editing your post. Your question is still pretty broad, but I've posted a general answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend googling something like "Processing array" or "Java array" for a ton of results.

[The Processing reference](https://processing.org/reference/) is a great first place to start. [Here](https://processing.org/reference/Array.html) is the reference for arrays in Processing, and it includes sample code like this:

```
int[] numbers = new int[3];
numbers[0] = 90;  // Assign value to first element in the array
numbers[1] = 150; // Assign value to second element in the array
numbers[2] = 30;  // Assign value to third element in the array
int a = numbers[0] + numbers[1]; // Sets variable 'a' to 240
int b = numbers[1] + numbers[2]; // Sets variable 'b' to 180
```

Shameless self-promotion: [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/arrays) is a tutorial on arrays in Processing.

Comment: thanks for your effort. but i still can't figure it out how to do it :/

Comment: @nilezguy Which part is giving you trouble? Start with something simpler. Create an array using hard-coded values. Get that working first, then try to add in more logic. Then if you get stuck, you can post a [mcve] along with a more specific technical question. Good luck.